# Twilio API | Real Time CallBackStatus in PHP/Symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, http, twilio, twilio-php

I am using the **Twilio API** for making calls/texting. A user initiates a call on a **Single Page Application** (with PHP/**Symfony 5**). I would like to display the status of the call **in real time** *(in progress, finished, ect... via StatusCallbackEvent)* as well as the digits once the call is finished.

The application works as follows:

1. The user initiates a call on the app (with a onClick event)
2. AJAX request to my controller
3. The controller makes the call
4. the API returns StatusCallBack data on another URL linked to another controller

How can I retrieve the data from the API in my AJAX request to display the result to the user ? Knowing that this is a Single Page App...

CallbackStatus goes here:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/back/", name="app_back")
 */
public function back (Request $request) : Response
{
    // some stuff...

    $voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse ();

    $response = new Response (
        $voiceResponse->asXML(),
        Response::HTTP_OK,
        ['content-type' => 'application/xml']
    );

    return $response;
}
```

I want to transfer it here:

```js
$.post({
    url  : "/makecall/",
    data: {
        "people" : idPeople
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // Display data here :(
    }
});
```

I hope to have been clear. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You can not just “transfer” the data to this point in your original AJAX call that triggered the whole process. You will need to poll the server to figure out whether the update has already arrived at the callback URL, or trigger a server push from there.

Comment: Thank you very much @CBroe for this answer. It opened positions for me for the future, in particular via the SSE/Web Socket. I discovered the [Mercure protocole](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html) for Symfony which will help me a lot.